# Create object list with for loop (python)

Tags: python, arrays, class, object, for-loop

The following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

class TestClass:
    container = []

testList = []

for i in range(2) :
    testList.append(TestClass())
    for j in range(4) :
        testList[i].container.append(j)

for i in range(2):
    print testList[i].container
```

returns the following:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3]
```

I'm puzzled as to why... I would expect it to be:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3]
[0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Can someone help me what I'm missing here? I'm new to python I have a C/C++ background. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The reason is that TestClass.container is a class attribute, not an instance attribute. Define container in the constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not how you do members in Python.

Or, rather, it's how you do it when you want a *class attribute*: Instead of each `TestClass` instance having its own separate `container` member, they all share a single one. (Since you mentioned your C++ background, this is similar to a `static` member in C++, although not quite identical, so don't try to take that analogy too far.)

That's not what you want here; you want an *instance attribute*. The normal way to do that is to just create one in the `__init__` method (which is like the C++ constructor—although, again, not exactly like it):

```
class TestClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.container = []
```

And yes, this means that if you really want to, you can create two different `TestClass` instances that, despite being the same type, have completely different members.

While we're at it, in Python 2.x, you never* want to write `class TestClass:`. Use `class TestClass(object):` instead.

You probably want to read through the [Classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) chapter of the official tutorial, or some equivalent explanation elsewhere. Python classes are very different from C++ classes in a lot of ways.

---

<sub>* There are some exceptions where you at least arguably want it, but you don't want to learn about those now.</sub>